# Which byte(Alpha, Red, Green, Blue) is wrong when converting byte array with color space of 8BitARGB to BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage

I have got the image byte array in the color space of 8BitARGB and need to convert this byte array to **java.awt.BufferedImage**.
The code is like:

```
public void getImage(byte byteArray[]){
        int height = 1920;
        int width = 1080;
        ARGB_to_ABGR(byteArray);
        BufferedImage image1 = new BufferedImage(height, width, 
                BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
        image1.getWritableTile(0, 0).setDataElements(0, 0, height, width, byteArray);
        java.io.File file = new java.io.File("amazing.png");
        try {
            ImageIO.write(image1, "jpg", file);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    /*
     * Swap the Red byte and Blue byte
     */
    public void ARGB_to_ABGR(byte byteArray[]){
        int length = byteArray.length;
        byte r = 0;
        byte b = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < byteArray.length; i++){
            if(length % 4 == 0){
                //do nothing
            }else if(length % 4 == 1){
                r = byteArray[i];
            }else if(length % 4 == 2){
                //do nothing
            }else if(length % 4 == 3){
                b = byteArray[i];
                byteArray[i] = r;
                byteArray[i - 2] = b;
            }
        }
    }
```

The original image looks like:
[image]

The amazing.png looks like:
[image]

I don't think the original byte array has any problem. For quick debug, just based on the image effect,can anyone tell which byte(Alpha, Red, Green, Blue) is wrong? Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code for `ARGB_to_ABGR` you probably wanted to write `i % 4` where you now have `length % 4`. As it is currently, I guess it is doing nothing at all.

Comment: Thanks. It's actually a stupid typo. However, after modifying the code. The image is still not what I want. Maybe the byte order of 8BitARGB is not A,R,G,B actually. I will enum all possibilities. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I think @Henry is right in that there's just a simple typo in your code. However, I'd like to provide an alternative way of writing this, which is (to me at least) easier to read/understand, and thus less error prone.

I believe it's also faster, as it does no testing on the indexes.

This version iterates over the input byte array one pixel (4 bytes) at a time:

```
public void ARGB_to_ABGR(byte[] byteArray) {
    byte tempR = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < byteArray.length; i += 4) {
        // For each iteration, simply swap R and B
        tempR = byteArray[i + 1];
        byteArray[i + 1] = byteArray[i + 3];
        byteArray[i + 3] = tempR;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It looks concise.